# Account Merge Trigger Execution Order

Tags: apex, trigger, merge, order-of-execution

When account is merged, what's the expected trigger order? Does the wining account get updated first or does the losing account get deleted? What happens when the child records are reparented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm)

> ## Triggers and Merge Statements
>
> Merge events do not fire their own trigger events. Instead, they fire delete and update events as
>   follows:
>
> ### Deletion of losing records
>
> A single merge operation fires a single delete event for all records
>   that are deleted in the merge. To determine which records were deleted
>   as a result of a merge operation use the `MasterRecordId` field in
>   `Trigger.old`. When a record is deleted after losing a merge
>   operation, its MasterRecordId field is set to the `Id` of the winning
>   record. The `MasterRecordId` field is only set in `after delete`
>   trigger events. If your application requires special handling for
>   deleted records that occur as a result of a merge, you need to use the
>   `after delete` trigger event.
>
> ### Update of the winning record
>
> A single merge operation fires a single update event for the winning record only. Any child records that are
>   reparented as a result of the merge operation **do not fire
>   triggers**.
>
> ### Example
>
> For example, if two contacts are merged, only the delete and update contact triggers fire. No triggers for records related to
>   the contacts, such as accounts or opportunities, fire.
>
> ### Trigger Order of Execution The following is the order of events when a merge occurs:
>
> 1. The `before delete` trigger fires.
> 2. The system deletes the necessary records due to the merge, assigns new parent records to the child records, and sets the `MasterRecordId`
>      field on the deleted records.
> 3. The `after delete` trigger fires.
> 4. The system does the specific updates required for the master record. Normal update triggers apply.

Comment: So how can you get triggers on the children to fire? I have an `on update` trigger on my child object. How can I get those to fire? Do I have to write a new trigger on the parent object, and if so how can I do that when `MasterRecordId` is not set until after the `before delete` yet the child records won't have the deleted parentID in the `after delete` trigger?

Comment: @Chance great question, and one i'd think would warrant it's own separate questions since i'm sure you're not the only one whose wondered this. high level, you'd need two parts, in the before delete you need to get a list of all the account ids, and then build a map of all related child records you care about firing the triggers on related to those ids. at this point you won't truly know if it's a merge or not, but need to have the information in case it is

Comment: @chance then, when the after delete fires, you can figure out which records were actually merged, by virtue of their id being present in your maps. you can then use the maps to find the related record and do an update call to fire triggers on them